# ZF2 session and redirect works only in local server

Tags: php, session, redirect, zend-framework2

Good Morning!

I developed a system in ZF2 on my local server but when migrating to the web server, I noticed some strange things. I also tested on a third server and the mystery continues. In the error log nothing appears. The session does not work, the data simply is not persisted. I also noticed that redirects do not work. I'm using Apache and PHP 7.1

Code for session:

```
$this->session = new Container('search');
if( !empty($this->params()->fromPost('search')) ){
    $this->session->offsetSet('search', $this->params()->fromPost('search') );
}
return $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(200)->setContent(Json::encode(
    $this->session->offsetGet('search')
));
```

Code for redirect:

```
if( !$logged ){
    $this->redirect()->toRoute("login", array(
        'controller' => 'login',
        'action' => 'index'
    ));
}
```

Comment: I guess you have error reporting disabled. Turn it on and tell if something is wrong (since redirect does not work then there must be some kind of error)

Comment: Unfortunately, the error report is enabled because errors that result from data that is not persisted in the session are displayed, but no error appears as to why this data is not persisted.

Comment: I solved the problem. Were the tags ?> <?php in a certain file (in that order) that were causing the error that, curiously, did not appear at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should use return statment, while calling redirect plugin.

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute("login", array(
        'controller' => 'login',
        'action' => 'index'
    ));
```

It should helps.